# Comment system database design

Tags: asp.net, database-design

I'm developing a system like SO (completely different topic) and replies and comments are alike with the system we see everyday on StackOverflow.

My question is, I'm loading the question with a Stored PROC, loading replies with another Stored PROC and now I'm adding comment system. Do I need to fetch the comments 1 by 1 for each of the replies on topic?

This means that if I have my page size set to 20 replies, I'll be doing 22 database operations which is more than I was thinking.

I don't think I need to add my database diagram for this question but still here it is:

```
Questions
-----------
QUESTION_ID
USER_ID
QUESTION_TEXT
DATE

REPLIES
-----------
REPLY_ID
QUESTION_ID
USER_ID
REPLY_TEXT
DATE

COMMENTS
------------
REPLY_ID (fk replies)
USER_ID
TEXT
DATE
```

Comment: Might be different topic from SO but are you aware there are sites covering many subjects in the StackExchange family?  Just making sure you know before you go up against the big dog ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get all your comments at once.

Then make `DataView`s from the result with a filter for each reply and bind to that `DataView`.  You could also use linq to entities and just filter out new sets on each bind.  Here is a basic pseudo code example:

1. Get all comments for all replies to question
2. Bind replies
3. Implement the `OnDataBinding` for the reply control that will display the comments
4. In the `OnDataBinding` add a filter to the result set for the comments with the same reply ID
5. Bind the filtered list of comments to the display control for comments

This should work and I have implement the same scenario for similar types of data structures.

Comment: This is what I needed, will get back if I face any problems. Hope you'll be here in 30 minutes :)

Comment: I can't access the nested repeater from codebehind. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pabuc Implement the `OnDataBinding` of the nested repeater. In that event is where you will be doing the filtering. You don't have to search for it.

Comment: Ok I guess I'm finished with this :) One last question. I've added a relation on 2 columns (the example data structure is not the actual structure, I have 2 columns as pk) and I'm worried about performance issues. I've tried to use Select() instead of relations but couldn't bind the datarow[] with column names. I guess I have to use index instead of column names for that. That is another point but would I have any performance issues with relations? There can be a lot of comments for a single page..

Comment: @Pabuc I prefer to have a single PK field unless there is so weird case where it can't be done.  As for lots of comments on your select you could bring the top 5 comments for each reply and maybe a total count of comments related to the reply.  Then if the total is greater than 5 you could have a button appear that lets you manually get the rest of the comments.  Most people are usually just interested in the latest comments anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Pabuc,

For your initial Question, why not get all the results using a single Query for the given question / reply ?

```
select reply_text, user_id 
  from REPLIES
  order by DATE asc
```

Also, as you pointed out, except for the minor differences, the question and answer have almost the same attributes as that of a post.

Wouldn't a model like the one below make more sense? The Question and Answer are both "posts" with the only difference being an answer has the question as the parent and the question has no parent.

```
Create table post -- question/reply (
   post_id number,
   parent_post_id number, -- will be null if it is the question, will have the question id
                          -- if it is a reply to a question
   post_text varchar2(4000),
   user_id   number,
       post_date date);

-self referential foreign key
Alter table post
  add constraint foreign key (parent_post_id) references post(post_id);
```

--comments to all posts (questions/replies).

```
create table comments(
  comment_id number,
  post_id number,
  comment_txt varchar2(140),
  comment_user_id number,
  comment_date  date
);

alter table comments add constraint fk_comments_post
  foreign key (post_id) references post(post_id).
```

-- for a given Question (post) id, you can get all the replies and posts using...

```
select replies.*,
       comments.*
  from posts replies,
       comments
  where replies.parent_id = :Question_id --input
    and comments.post_id = replies.post_id
```

You might have to add an order by clause to get the results based on points, updated_timestamp or any other attribute as needed.

Comment: thank you for your post. I've no problem with fetching the replies in a single query. I'm stuck with the comments. How would you fetch the replies and comments for each reply in a single query?

Comment: Pabuc -- Updated my poast above with the sample query.